# Getting a java bean property value by annotation

Tags: java, annotations

How do I get the returned value from a java bean property by annotation?

For example, trying to get the returned value of the property id from a Hibernate entity using its annotation (@Id).

Thanks.

Edit:

I've eliminated the requirement of using javassist for this question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much details about javassit internal except that hibernate uses it internally, but surely can tell you that spring reflection util have a powerful support for handling things like processing all the classes which have an annotation on properties[e.g.] [user defined or not].In case you don't find success with javassist, give a try to spring reflection api.